# C# telerik RadGridView - check for empty column

Tags: c#, telerik, cell, radgridview

I have a button which calculate a column with custom formula, but if the whole column is empty (for example there are 10 rows, but the cells are empty) and click the button then VS will shows an exception because there are no any records to work with. So before to do anything how to validate the column if has at least one not empty cell? One simple if condition would do the job, but how to check it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are saying that, you have a **button**. So in that `button_Click()` event. 
put a `try`, `catch` block.

like below

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    //Your code logic for custom formula
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    //just throw or leave blank
  }
}
```